# gallery indicator in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have added a CSS gallery template in my html code.That code originally has 4 images in it. I added nine more images but now the indicator in that gallery does not move after 4 images and preview of other nine images is also not visible.

Original CSS code: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/2oko1

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="carousel">

<input type="radio" id="image1" name="gallery-control" checked>
<input type="radio" id="image2" name="gallery-control">
<input type="radio" id="image3" name="gallery-control">
<input type="radio" id="image4" name="gallery-control">
<input type="radio" id="image5" name="gallery-control">
<input type="radio" id="image6" name="gallery-control">
<input type="radio" id="image7" name="gallery-control">
<input type="radio" id="image8" name="gallery-control">
<input type="radio" id="image9" name="gallery-control">
<input type="radio" id="image10" name="gallery-control">
<input type="radio" id="image11" name="gallery-control">
<input type="radio" id="image12" name="gallery-control">
<input type="radio" id="image13" name="gallery-control">




<input type="checkbox" id="fullscreen" name="gallery-fullscreen-control"/>

<div class="wrap">

  <figure>
    <label for="fullscreen">
      <img src="a1.jpg" alt="image1"/>
    </label>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <label for="fullscreen">
      <img src="a2.jpg" alt="image2"/>
    </label>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <label for="fullscreen">
      <img src="a3.jpg" alt="image3" />
    </label>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <label for="fullscreen">
      <img src="a4.jpg" alt="image4"/>
    </label>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <label for="fullscreen">
      <img src="a5.jpg" alt="image5"/>
    </label>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <label for="fullscreen">
      <img src="a6.jpg" alt="image6"/>
    </label>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <label for="fullscreen">
      <img src="a7.jpg" alt="Arfa Singing"/>
    </label>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <label for="fullscreen">
      <img src="a8.jpg" alt="Arfa Singing"/>
    </label>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <label for="fullscreen">
      <img src="a9.jpg" alt="Arfa Singing"/>
    </label>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <label for="fullscreen">
      <img src="a10.jpg" alt="Arfa Singing"/>
    </label>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <label for="fullscreen">
      <img src="a11.jpg" alt="Arfa Singing"/>
    </label>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <label for="fullscreen">
      <img src="a12.jpg" alt="Arfa Singing"/>
    </label>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <label for="fullscreen">
      <img src="a13.jpg" alt="Arfa Singing"/>
    </label>
  </figure>
</div>

<div class="thumbnails">

  <div class="slider"><div class="indicator"></div></div>

  <label for="image1" class="thumb" style="background-image: url('a1.jpg')"></label>

  <label for="image2" class="thumb" style="background-image: url('a2.jpg')"></label>

  <label for="image3" class="thumb" style="background-image: url('a3.jpg')"></label>

  <label for="image4" class="thumb" style="background-image: url('a4.jpg')"></label>

  <label for="image5" class="thumb" style="background-image: url('a5.jpg')"></label>

  <label for="image6" class="thumb" style="background-image: url('a6.jpg')"></label>

  <label for="image7" class="thumb" style="background-image: url('a7.jpg')"></label>

  <label for="image8" class="thumb" style="background-image: url('a8.jpg')"></label>

  <label for="image9" class="thumb" style="background-image: url('a9.jpg')"></label>

  <label for="image10" class="thumb" style="background-image: url('a10.jpg')"></label>

  <label for="image11" class="thumb" style="background-image: url('a11.jpg')"></label>

  <label for="image12" class="thumb" style="background-image: url('a12.jpg')"></label>

  <label for="image13" class="thumb" style="background-image: url('a13.jpg')"></label>
</div>
```

Here is CSS:

```
.gallery {
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  width: 70%;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.gallery input[name$="control"] {
  display: none;
}
.gallery .carousel {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
  height: 70vh;
  width: 100%;
}
.gallery .wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: static;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.gallery .wrap figure {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.05s;
  transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0.05s;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
          transform: translateX(0%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  opacity: 1;
}
.gallery .wrap figure label {
  cursor: zoom-in;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.gallery .wrap figure img {
  cursor: inherit;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.gallery .thumbnails {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1;
          flex: 1;
  min-width: 60px;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      -ms-flex-positive: 0;
          flex-grow: 0;
  -ms-flex-item-align: center;
      align-self: center;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: auto;
      flex-basis: auto;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 10px;
  z-index: 20;
}
.gallery .thumbnails .thumb {
  min-width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  opacity: 0.7;
  margin: 5px 0;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
      flex-shrink: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.gallery .thumbnails .slider {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  height: calc(60px + 10px);
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.33s cubic-bezier(0.3, 0, 0.33, 1);
  transition: all 0.33s cubic-bezier(0.3, 0, 0.33, 1);
}
.gallery .thumbnails .slider .indicator {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  max-height: calc(100% - 10px);
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: #428BFF;
  border-radius: 1px;
}
.gallery input#fullscreen:checked ~ .wrap figure {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
          animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.gallery input#fullscreen:checked ~ .wrap figure label {
  cursor: zoom-out;
}
.gallery input#fullscreen:checked ~ .wrap figure label img {
  -webkit-animation: shadow 0.2s;
          animation: shadow 0.2s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
          animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-direction: forwards;
          animation-direction: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.gallery input#image1:checked ~ .wrap figure {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
          transform: translateX(0);
}
.gallery input#image1:checked ~ .wrap figure:not(:nth-of-type(1)) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.gallery input#image1:checked ~ .thumbnails .slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
          transform: translateY(0);
}
.gallery input#image1:checked ~ .thumbnails .thumb:nth-of-type(1) {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: default;
}
.gallery input#image2:checked ~ .wrap figure {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
          transform: translateX(-100%);
}
.gallery input#image2:checked ~ .wrap figure:not(:nth-of-type(2)) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.gallery input#image2:checked ~ .thumbnails .slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
          transform: translateY(100%);
}
.gallery input#image2:checked ~ .thumbnails .thumb:nth-of-type(2) {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: default;
}
.gallery input#image3:checked ~ .wrap figure {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%);
          transform: translateX(-200%);
}
.gallery input#image3:checked ~ .wrap figure:not(:nth-of-type(3)) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.gallery input#image3:checked ~ .thumbnails .slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(200%);
          transform: translateY(200%);
}
.gallery input#image3:checked ~ .thumbnails .thumb:nth-of-type(3) {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: default;
}
.gallery input#image4:checked ~ .wrap figure {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-300%);
          transform: translateX(-300%);
}
.gallery input#image4:checked ~ .wrap figure:not(:nth-of-type(4)) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.gallery input#image4:checked ~ .thumbnails .slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(300%);
          transform: translateY(300%);
}
.gallery input#image4:checked ~ .thumbnails .thumb:nth-of-type(4) {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: default;
}


.gallery input#image5:checked ~ .wrap figure {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-300%);
          transform: translateX(-300%);
}
.gallery input#image5:checked ~ .wrap figure:not(:nth-of-type(5)) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.gallery input#image5:checked ~ .thumbnails .slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(300%);
          transform: translateY(300%);
}
.gallery input#image5:checked ~ .thumbnails .thumb:nth-of-type(5) {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: default;
}

.gallery input#image6:checked ~ .wrap figure {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-300%);
          transform: translateX(-300%);
}
.gallery input#image6:checked ~ .wrap figure:not(:nth-of-type(6)) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.gallery input#image6:checked ~ .thumbnails .slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(300%);
          transform: translateY(300%);
}
.gallery input#image6:checked ~ .thumbnails .thumb:nth-of-type(6) {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: default;
}
.gallery input#image7:checked ~ .wrap figure {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-300%);
          transform: translateX(-300%);
}
.gallery input#image7:checked ~ .wrap figure:not(:nth-of-type(7)) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.gallery input#image7:checked ~ .thumbnails .slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(300%);
          transform: translateY(300%);
}
.gallery input#image7:checked ~ .thumbnails .thumb:nth-of-type(7) {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: default;
}
.gallery input#image8:checked ~ .wrap figure {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-300%);
          transform: translateX(-300%);
}
.gallery input#image8:checked ~ .wrap figure:not(:nth-of-type(8)) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.gallery input#image8:checked ~ .thumbnails .slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(300%);
          transform: translateY(300%);
}
.gallery input#image8:checked ~ .thumbnails .thumb:nth-of-type(8) {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: default;
}
.gallery input#image9:checked ~ .wrap figure {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-300%);
          transform: translateX(-300%);
}
.gallery input#image9:checked ~ .wrap figure:not(:nth-of-type(9)) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.gallery input#image9:checked ~ .thumbnails .slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(300%);
          transform: translateY(300%);
}
.gallery input#image9:checked ~ .thumbnails .thumb:nth-of-type(9) {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: default;
}
.gallery input#image10:checked ~ .wrap figure {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-300%);
          transform: translateX(-300%);
}
.gallery input#image10:checked ~ .wrap figure:not(:nth-of-type(10)) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.gallery input#image10:checked ~ .thumbnails .slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(300%);
          transform: translateY(300%);
}
.gallery input#image10:checked ~ .thumbnails .thumb:nth-of-type(10) {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: default;
}
.gallery input#image11:checked ~ .wrap figure {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-300%);
          transform: translateX(-300%);
}
.gallery input#image11:checked ~ .wrap figure:not(:nth-of-type(11)) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.gallery input#image11:checked ~ .thumbnails .slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(300%);
          transform: translateY(300%);
}
.gallery input#image11:checked ~ .thumbnails .thumb:nth-of-type(11) {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: default;
}
.gallery input#image12:checked ~ .wrap figure {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-300%);
          transform: translateX(-300%);
}
.gallery input#image12:checked ~ .wrap figure:not(:nth-of-type(12)) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.gallery input#image12:checked ~ .thumbnails .slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(300%);
          transform: translateY(300%);
}
.gallery input#image12:checked ~ .thumbnails .thumb:nth-of-type(12) {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: default;
}
.gallery input#image13:checked ~ .wrap figure {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-300%);
          transform: translateX(-300%);
}
.gallery input#image13:checked ~ .wrap figure:not(:nth-of-type(13)) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.gallery input#image13:checked ~ .thumbnails .slider {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(300%);
          transform: translateY(300%);
}
.gallery input#image13:checked ~ .thumbnails .thumb:nth-of-type(13) {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: default;
}
@-webkit-keyframes full {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.8);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.8);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes full {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.8);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.8);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes shadow {
  from {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmin rgba(24, 33, 45, 0), 0 0 10vmin rgba(13, 21, 31, 0);
  }
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmin rgba(24, 33, 45, 0.6), 0 0 10vmin rgba(13, 21, 31, 0.6);
  }
}
@keyframes shadow {
  from {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmin rgba(24, 33, 45, 0), 0 0 10vmin rgba(13, 21, 31, 0);
  }
  to {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vmin rgba(24, 33, 45, 0.6), 0 0 10vmin rgba(13, 21, 31, 0.6);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to say if I don't see your example running, but I think the problem is that you have not incremented the `transform: translate` property in `gallery input#image-x` selectors according to the number of slides.

If you pay attention to the first 4 rules, the percentage increases in 100 per cent in each rule, but in the fifth rule the `transform` property remain in 300%.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Sir i can say that you are legend. I've been trying to solve this for 2 days no one could help me. Thank you so much it worked just perfectly.